# Photomatching in Blender possible?

Tags: mesh, camera

One function I'd like to see in Blender is the possibility of matching 3D geometry to photos. The method I have in mind consists of picking corresponding points between the mesh and a photo of the same mesh. When multiple points are picked this gives enough information for finding out the camera location in the photo.  Some (expensive) software already has this feature, like 3Ds max, Rhino and FormZ. I wonder if anyone knows of any script that makes this possible in Blender, or might be able to help me figure out how to setup this operation in blender. I'll describe the operation, step by step.

1. Load a 3D mesh.
2. Load a photo that features an identical 3D mesh from any angle as background image.
3. Pick point on 3D mesh (for example: left corner of building)
4. Pick corresponding point on photo (in this example: left corner of building).
5. Repeat step 3-4, X amount of times, picking different points.
6. Making use of information from step 3-X to position the camera so that the 3D mesh "matches" the background image.

It would be awesome if there might a way to do this in blender, either by a script or manually.

Thanks for any help, and have a wonderful day!

Comment: Did you see/try this? https://github.com/stuffmatic/blam

Comment: NO. There is no such functionality in blender. Currently you can only do photo matching manually. Tools like  blam might help, but the tool does not calculate camera placement by correlating points in the geometry with matching features in an image.

Comment: When I think about some perfect software/script and I learn it doesn't exist, there are two things I can do. One: wait around for somebody to make it. Two: write the script myself. Option number two is very rewarding :)

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely looking for BLAM.

"A camera and projector calibration toolkit for Blender that also does automatic 3D reconstruction of geometry with rectangular faces."

https://github.com/stuffmatic/blam

See this introduction video:
https://vimeo.com/35153437 and other videos and documentation listed there.

It does not match an existing mesh though, it creates it for you...
There's other methods too, perhaps using the camera tracker over a sequence of images.